How to remove appsmith water mark after deploying it?
I have set up Appsmith locally on my system and deployed an application. When viewing the deployed application, I noticed there is a watermark in the bottom right that says Built on Appsmith. I want to completely remove this watermark.
I have looked through the Appsmith documentation and tried searching online, but I couldn't find any clear instructions on how to remove this watermark. Is there a configuration setting or a specific way to deploy the application that allows me to remove this watermark entirely?

So to remove this water mark , you can visit  the following directory and comment out that function  or its return content . Also comment down or remove  the funciton in the entire code to avoid errors.
The directory is

src/pages/AppViewer/BrandingBadge.tsx

